# XSLT one-level grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

INPUT:

```
<Root>
<line id="1">
    <subline name="id">23</subline>
    <subline name="text">mic</subline>
    <subline name="Available">yes</subline>
    <subline name="Unavailable"/>
</line>
<line id="2">
    <subline name="id">23</subline>
    <subline name="text">XrJ</subline>
    <subline name="Available"/>
    <subline name="Unavailable">yes</subline>
</line>
<line id="3">
    <subline name="id">23</subline>
    <subline name="text">mare</subline>
    <subline name="Available"/>
    <subline name="Unavailable">yes</subline>
</line>
<line id="4">
    <subline name="id">574</subline>
    <subline name="text">mic</subline>
    <subline name="Available">yes</subline>
    <subline name="Unavailable"/>
</line>
<line id="5">
    <subline name="id">574</subline>
    <subline name="text">centrer</subline>
    <subline name="Available">yes</subline>
    <subline name="Unavailable"/>
</line>
</Root>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<Root>
<update>
    <id>23</id>
    <reqUpdate>
        <diff>
            <text>mic</text>
            <available>yes</available>
        </diff>
        <diff>
            <text>XrJ</text>
            <unavailable>yes</unavailable>
        </diff>
        <diff>
            <text>mare</text>
            <unavailable>yes</unavailable>
        </diff>
    </reqUpdate>
</update>
<update>
    <id>574</id>
    <reqUpdate>
        <diff>
            <text>mic</text>
            <available>yes</available>
        </diff>
        <diff>
            <text>centrer</text>
            <available>yes</available>
        </diff>
    </reqUpdate>
</update>
</Root>
```

My desire is that for each unique ID to build different "DIFF" tags with the values from the subline 'TEXT' and add if that text is available or unavailable as you can see we have this information in the subline -'available' / 'unavailable'

So, for-each unique ID in the "DIFF" tag should have the values from text (from each record) and with the tags "available"  or "unavailable" with the text = YES.

I can't seem to grasp how to do something like this, every xsl I've worked on returned nothing so I gave up and now I am stuck.

Please help and many thanks for helping a noob.

EDIT:

MY XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:key name="record" match="line" use="subline[@name='id']"/>
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="line[generate-id(.)=
  generate-id(key('record',subline[@name='id'])[1])]">
            <update>
                <id>
    <xsl:value-of select="subline   [@name='id']"/>
                </id>
                <reqUpdate>
                    <xsl:variable name="values" select="key('record',subline[@name='id'])/subline[@name='Available']"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$values">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$values">
                                <dif>
                                    <text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="./subline[name='text']"/>
                                    </text>
                                    <available>yes</available>
                                </dif>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="not($values)">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$values">
                                <dif>
                                    <text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="./subline[name='text']"/>
                                    </text>
                                    <unavailable>yes</unavailable>
                                </dif>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </reqUpdate>
            </update>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my current output:

```
enter code here
    <Root>
<update>
    <id>23</id>
    <reqUpdate>
        <dif>
            <text/>
            <available>yes</available>
        </dif>
        <dif>
            <text/>
            <available>yes</available>
        </dif>
        <dif>
            <text/>
            <available>yes</available>
        </dif>
    </reqUpdate>
</update>
<update>
    <id>574</id>
    <reqUpdate>
        <dif>
            <text/>
            <available>yes</available>
        </dif>
        <dif>
            <text/>
            <available>yes</available>
        </dif>
    </reqUpdate>
</update>
</Root>
```

Comment: If you know that  you need to apply [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) (i.e. you work with an XSLT 1.0 processor), then why don't you do exactly that? If you have tried and failed, please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Hello. Updated..it's close enough but not quite there yet and I'm not sure what I am missing. Thank you!

Comment: Are you forced to use XSLT 1.0? In version 2.0 you could use for-each-group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="record" match="line" use="subline[@name='id']"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="line[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('record',subline[@name='id'])[1])]">
            <update>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="subline[@name='id']"/>
                </id>
                <reqUpdate>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('record', subline[@name='id'])">
                        <diff>
                            <text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="subline[@name='text']"/>
                            </text>
                            <xsl:if test="subline[@name='Available']='yes'">
                                <available>yes</available>
                            </xsl:if>
                           <xsl:if test="subline[@name='Unavailable']='yes'">
                                <unavailable>yes</unavailable>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </diff>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </reqUpdate>
            </update>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. IMHO, the target structure is not optimal; I would prefer to have a node with a constant *name* (e.g. `available`) and changing *content* (e.g. `yes` or `no`). The way you have it now will be just as awkward to process as the original.